# Can I play as anyone else in Kirby's Return to Dreamland?

Tags: kirby-return-to-dreamland

The likelyhood of me getting anyone else to play with me is pretty low, but I like the idea of being able to use Waddle-Dee/Meta Knight/King Dedede.

Is it possible to play any part of the game as a different character when playing by yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unlock the other three guys for Arena once you beat it with Kirby, I believe. Other than that you'll just have to stick with Hammer/Sword/Spear Kirby.

Disappointment aside, you have to remember that there are quite a few parts of the game (namely the Sphere Doomer sublevels) that I'm pretty sure you cannot pass without Kirby's ability to inhale the grey blocks.

> Also, there are two boss battles that you need to use Super Abilities to win.

Comment: Though you don't really need to go through those parts in order to progress through the game, you can ignore them completely.

Comment: True but I felt it was still worth mentioning. Actually now that I think about you couldn't even get into those areas without a Kirby with a Super Ability - which leads into the (spoilered) edit I just made.

Comment: Ah, I think that addition really seals it then.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible.

Kirby is really the main character of the game and the others are just supporting characters.  I don't think they've designed the game to allow you to use them as the first player.  AFAIK, you *must* play as Kirby when the first player.  When you're alone, that means you.

This is definitely true for the Main mode.  There is however an "Extra" mode after beating Main mode and I noticed a few subtle changes (e.g., you have half your normal life, some enemies are larger making them harder to defeat and possibly more).  <s>You *might* be able to play as them then but I don't know for sure, I haven't played all the way through that mode yet.</s>  It doesn't seem like you will be able to here either.

Answer (score 0):

So far, no.  You always have to be Kirby when playing by yourself, unless you have installed an action replay for Wii.